# How do I save two sets of information in different tables in the same SQLite Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm working on a budgeting app and I would like to ask the user to add income and expenses and then I would like to have the sum of the two sets of data in an overview activity. I researched online and found that putting the values into 2 different tables is the best way.(If you have any other ideas please  tell me.)
How would I put the income and expense on different tables and then how do I link them to get the sum?
I have completed saving the data for the expense in one table but do not know how to make another table for income. Forgive me for not knowing the best way to do this because I am new to using SQLite.

**add_expense.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class add_expense extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDbexpense;
    EditText editAmountexpense, editDateexpense, editNotesexpense;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_expense);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_expense);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Add Expense");
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_back));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        myDbexpense = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        editAmountexpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.amount_expense);
        editDateexpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date_expense);
        editNotesexpense = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.notes_expense);
        AddData();


        Spinner spinner;
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.categorydropdown_expense);
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.expensecategory_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position) + " selected as category", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

    }

    public void AddData(){
            FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_tick_expense);
            fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    boolean isInserted;
                    if (myDbexpense.insertData(
                            editAmountexpense.getText().toString(),
                            editDateexpense.getText().toString(),
                            editNotesexpense.getText().toString())) {
                        isInserted = true;
                        Intent intent=new Intent(add_expense.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else isInserted = false;
                    if(isInserted == true)
                        Toast.makeText(add_expense.this,"Data Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(add_expense.this,"Data not Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

The same has been done to create add_income.java.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.view.View;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHelper";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "expense.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "expense_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "AMOUNT";
    public static final String COL_3 = "DATE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "NOTES";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,AMOUNT INTEGER,DATE INTEGER,NOTES TEXT)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(String amount, String date, String notes) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2, amount);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, date);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, notes);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return res;
    }

    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL_1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String amount, String date, String notes) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, id);
        contentValues.put(COL_2, amount);
        contentValues.put(COL_3, date);
        contentValues.put(COL_4, notes);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteData(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[]{id});
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either create two tables in the `onCreate` method of your `DatabaseHelper` class and handle insert/read accordingly. Or if you want to use a single table, use negative values for expenses and positive value for income.

There are a number ways to handle this. Just you need to design and decide how to implement it.